# Controlling the default cloning folder of a Git Repository

Tags: git

When we clone a git repository, we can ask git to create a directory to fill with the git directory thanks to the following command :

```
git --clone http://bitbucket.org/....../myrepo.git ToToFolder
```

Here, myrepo.git will be cloned into ToToFolder.

If I use the same command without forcing the cloning into ToToFolder, the clone will be done into the *"The "humanish" part of the source repository"* so into the folder myrepo.

I am creating a git repo, and I would like to control the name of the "by default cloning folder" without changing the name of my repo. So I have a repo called "myrepo.git" and I would like that if someone call :

```
git --clone http://bitbucket.org/....../myrepo.git
```

The repo be cloned into a folder called "ToToFolder".

Is it possible ? And if yes how can I manage it ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think this is hardcoded in Git and is always name of the remote repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No – changing the name the repo will have clientside is not possible. You could create a more elaborate solution that requires some settings on the server and a custom script on the clients, but I guess that’s not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I am not sure that an alias can solve my problem, because an alias will allow to deduce the clonning folder from the repository name... But if there is no "logic" between them, I will not be able to express my alias name. If for exemple I want that my repo : "myrepo.git" to be stored in MyRepo, I will not be able to find a rules to transform the "m" and the "r" into upper case... But thank you...

Comment: Now, I am agree with you answer ... So I will make a script on the client side, if there is no other way.